# Replicate data from DocumentDb in client

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

We are planning to use DocumentDb as storage for a new application. Is it possible to replicate/synchronise part of that data to client apps? Or does that require a different backend storage to work smoothly?
We are planning clients in Xamarin and WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentDB doesn't provide syncing to client/local stores out-of-the-box. As David mentioned, you may need to create a mechanism to handle this sync.

That said, the DocumentDB team might be able to help you solve your scenario via other features and abstractions, [e.g. using DocumentDB's change feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-change-feed). You can reach them by sending an e-mail to askdocdb {at} microsoft dot com.

Comment: Excellent answer! I am aware there is no client side version of DocumentDb, so I was looking for alternatives. The Change Feed looks very promising as it will help me to lookup changes since last time.

Comment: The provided GitHub sample looks like a good starting point: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/code-samples/ChangeFeed/Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

DocumentDB doesn't have a local-install version (aside from the emulator, but that's specifically for dev/test). You'd need to come up with your own data replication scheme, and choose an appropriate data persistence approach locally, for your Xamarin app.

I really can't address your question about choosing DocumentDB vs another database - that's really up to you to decide, based on your business needs, app needs, etc. and out-of-scope here (since it would be a tool recommendation, and opinion-soliciting).